# How to get specify field in arraylist and set to list using simple Java 8 code?

Tags: java

I have a list named `accountList`. Is there any simple Java 8 replacement for this loop?

```
List<Long> accountIdList = new ArrayList<Long>();
for(Account account: accountList){
    accountIdList.add(account.getId());
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "Java 8 replacement"? Those loops still exist in Java 8 (and its successors).

Answer (score 5):

You can do it like this:

```
List<Long> accountIdList = accountList.stream()
    .map(Account::getId)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. But one could argue if using streams indeed is simpler than using a loop.

Answer (score 1):

Hope you've written above `List` by mistake. If you want to use `Stream` then here's the code:

```
List<Long> accountIdList = accountList.stream().map(Account::getId).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just import the `Collectors` to save some code if you are using them a lot:

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;


List<Long> accountIdList = accountList.stream()
    .map(Account::getId)
    .collect(toList());
```